# Routing and OpenVPN

Tags: networking, openvpn, routing

O have small problem with routing and OpenVPN. After start of VPN connection all traffic goes through my OpenVPN server. But my server is behind ADSL router with 16/2 MBit Download/Upload speed. So i can get access to my internal servers but access to normal Internet is to slow.

But I'd like to make like this:[image]

As you see access to normal Internet is direct(without OpenVPN) and to my Internal server via OpenVPN.

How can i make it?

- Client laptop: Ubuntu 12.04, 14.04
- OpenVPN server Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Is there a `redirect-gateway` option in client's OpenVPN config file? If yes, then remove it.

Comment: Yes `redirect-gateway` is present in my OpenVPN config.  If i disable this option can i still work with internal server? Or i need extra configuration edits on client?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the OpenVPN client configuration file, remove the `redirect-gateway` option to stop redirection of all the traffic through the VPN.

If the server doesn't automatically push to clients the route to its LAN, you will lose access to your private servers. As a work around you could add the option `route <network> <netmask>` to your configuration file. For example, if your private servers have IP addresses in the 192.168.0.0/24 network add the following:

```
route 192.168.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

That would force through the VPN all traffic whose destination is the 192.168.0.0/24 network.

Comment: Thanks! In Network manager I under VPN->Edit->IPv4->Routes i checked box `Use this connection only for resources on it's network` Next i added route for network.